# How to show full article in Smart Search results

Tags: smartsearch

I want to show full article in smart Search results (including images and other html)

As i see i have to change the line 34

```
$description = JHtml::_('string.truncate', JString::substr($this->result->description, $start), $desc_length, true);
```

in
/html/com_finder/search/default_result.php 
but i dont know to what.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the above line to:

```
$description = $this->result->description;
```